# Why a subclass of the concrete class can be declared abstract, and some of the parent class methods can be overridden and declared abstract?

Tags: java, inheritance

Usually we declare the subclass of abstract class to be concrete and override the abstract methods to concrete. Does there exist a use for the opposite?

Comment: I didn't even realise this was possible until I read your question and tested it!  I can only think of one reason - where you want to force the subclasses to override a specific method.

Comment: This is too opinion/discussion-based for SO's format. You _might_ be able to get it focused enough for SO if you provide a specific example and ask specific questions about it, but even then it's probably too opinion-based.

Comment: That said, one possible use case is if you want a tighter method contract and want to force subclasses to obey that one, not the broader one established by the concrete base class.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't even think about this question until I was asked about this in the class. I really can't figure out why we need this. I can't even find an example.

Answer (score 8):

**One use case that comes to mind..**

Imagine you've got a class as follows..

```
public abstract class Animal {
    // Some stuff.
}
```

Then you say, okay, now I want a `Giraffe` class. `Giraffe` is specific, so there's no need to make it `abstract`..

```
public class Giraffe {
    // Some stuff that overrides or uses the Animal behaviour.
}
```

Now give it some time, when you've got six or seven applications that use your code.

Then, one day when you're bored, you decide to look up Giraffes on Wikipedia, and you find out that in fact, `Giraffe` is extremely vague! There's spotted Giraffes, Stripy Giraffes, Long legged Giraffes.. and all of these appear in different countries! So what do you do?

- You could change Giraffe into an `abstract` class and `extend` it in a sub class.. but you've already got a lot of applications using your code. Do you instantly render them obsolete and force a mass update?
- You can create further classes that describe more specific forms of `Giraffe`, but.. `StripyGiraffe` isn't specific enough.. unless you can make that class `abstract`..

**So what do you do?**

You take the latter option..

```
public abstract class StripyGiraffe extends Giraffe
```

And you can continue to extend it..

```
public class AfricanStripyGiraffe extends StripyGiraffe
```

That way, the old code works without a hitch, and you're still more than welcome to extend your object hierarchy as much as possible. You can maintain the integrity of your objects by declaring them as `abstract` when they're not specific enough to be instanciated, and using this method allows the user to still state.

```
Giraffe geoffrey = new AfricanStripyGiraffe();
```

Comment: Now THIS is a splendid use of animal life to explain programing questions!

Comment: I really wanted to edit in the whole of the animal kingdom but I thought it might convolute the concept.

Comment: Great answer! My only complaint -- it doesn't (directly) address the question of why concrete methods can be overridden by `abstract` methods that OP also posed (although the argument that applies to classes can pretty much be repeated for methods)

Comment: More often than not, functionality has several reasons. I think this is one good reason for that functionality. In fact, it's the only reason I can think of. I feel I've answered the question.. albeit with a lot of metaphors!

Answer (score -1):

In Java each class i derived from Object type. And this is kind of answer, when you create an abstract class form concrete class. You just declare the the implementation is not complete and should be detailed on lower layer of abstraction.